# NSDateFormatter gives wrong time (4 minutes difference!!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting NSDateComponents results in incorrect NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596358/setting-nsdatecomponents-results-in-incorrect-nsdate)

`NSDateFormatter` gives me ALMOST right results. The difference is just 4 minutes. Where... where it comes from??! (Time zone shift is 18000 sec = exactly 5 hours!)
(iOS 6)

```
NSDate* n = ...;
NSDateFormatter *gmtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[gmtFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[gmtFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
DLog(@"n = %@, formatted to = %@, timeZone = %@", n, [gmtFormatter stringFromDate:n], gmtFormatter.timeZone);
[gmtFormatter release];
```

Result:

> 2013-01-25 14:49:29.224 Dictionary[1321:907] n = 0001-01-01 18:57:02
>   +0000, formatted to = 2:01 PM, timeZone = America/New_York (EST) offset -18000

Comment: Because the date is prior to roughly 1965, the longitude is used to calculate time zone offset vs using "standard" time offsets.

Comment: Yes, correct. I just figured this out myself. The year is not set so time zones behave unpredictable. OMG! I spent 2 hour for this silly issue!!! Everybody - thank you very much!